# Php code not working, and turns into HTML comment

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have a file "index.html". And a code into it

```
<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
```

But in browser I can  see:

```
<!--<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>-->
```

I use   Microsoft-IIS/7.5server, so I cant use .htaccess file.

Comment: Try <?php //echo "Hello world"; ?>

Comment: rename your file to `index.php`.

Comment: If I rename - all works good. But I need .html extension

Comment: Why do you need `.html`? It won't work in a `.html` file because it's not HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791326/html-embedded-php-code-not-executing-when-hosted-on-iis may have some information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your file as index.php instead. HTML doesn't read PHP.

Edit: Try to change the home url then. Check this out:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Answer (score 0):

You can store your file with .php extension and user [rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in iis to link .html file to .php file that you store.
commonly for SEO Using this method.

Answer (score -2):

1. // This is a one-line c++ style commenting

Example

```
<?php
// This is a single line commment.
$comment = 1;

/* This is a multi line comment
       yet another line of comment */
$comment = "many lines";

?>
```