# Not able to run php code inside html from iis

Tags: php, html, iis

I have configured php in my machine with IIS, and i am able to check its success by launching phpinfo(). Php executes correctly in the files with php extension,*.php, inside the standard block:

```
<?php

... php code here

?>
```

But anything inline inside HTML does NOT execute. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Sample data
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Sample data
    </h1>
    This is from Sample data :  
    <?php 
          echo "Hello!!";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is just `This is from Sample data :`

Some of the post suggest to add a module mapping for *.html

Tried the settings that was mentioned in the post [html-embedded php code not executing when hosted on iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791326/html-embedded-php-code-not-executing-when-hosted-on-iis) still it was not working

[module mapping for *.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icnwT.jpg)

After adding this in the website level still its not working. Is there some setting or config I'm missing? Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html-embedded php code not executing when hosted on iis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791326/html-embedded-php-code-not-executing-when-hosted-on-iis)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791326/html-embedded-php-code-not-executing-when-hosted-on-iis

Comment: i did the same settings that were mentioned in the post, still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trail and errors i figured out that i need to add Handle Mapping for *.htm rather than *.html. Since all my webpages are using *.htm files adding the handle solved the issue. Now my PHP code is getting executed from htm files